# Orientability of differantiable manifold of orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds

I want to find out if differentiable manifold of matrices $M=\{A_{(3\times3)}(\mathbb{R}): A^TA=16E\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}=\mathbb{R}^9$ is orientable. It is only worth proving that orthogonal matrices form (or do not form) an orientable differentiable manifold.

I have tried to show that if there is a loop $\gamma(t)$, then normal vector $\vec{n}(t)$ to $M$ constructed from $\gamma(t)$ remains its orientation: $\forall t_0\;\vec{n}(t_0)=\vec{n}(t_0+1)$, but unfortunately got no results.

Comment: Your manifold is something called a Lie group.  Have you studied those?

Comment: No, I have not. I would really appreciate "differential" or "geometric" proof, without applying algebra.

Comment: An option might be to use the fact that each connected component of $M$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3/\{\pm1\}=\mathbf P^3(\mathbf R)$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3))).